# Javascript eventlisteners override other buttons?

Tags: javascript

I've run into a problem using eventlisteners and javascript (though onclick seems to have the same effect).

I have this in html

```
 <input id="srch" type="button" value="Zoek gebruikers!"  onclick="searchButton()">
```

Now, this initially worked fine and executes the expected javascript code. But, when I add this in another javascript function

```
var addbutton = document.createElement("input");
addbutton.setAttribute("id","openAddMenu");
addbutton.type = "button";
addbutton.value = "search";
addbutton.innerHTML = "Zoek";
addbutton.addEventListener('click',searchFriendsAsync(),false);
```

Now my initial button wil try to execute 'searchFriendAsync()' as well.

I'm quite inexperienced with javascript, so I'm sure it's something basic I'm missing. Yet search results on google find answers regarding adding one event to multiple buttons etc, which is .. about the opposite of what I want. I need multiple buttons with different events - some buttons are generated using javascript. (Note, when I add another eventlistener to a third button, both the first and second button will mess up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
addbutton.addEventListener( 'click', searchFriendsAsync(), false );
```

I assume `searchFriendsAsync` is a function defined in your code that you wish to call when `addbutton` is clicked, is that right?

That's not what this code does. It calls `searchFriendsAsync` *immediately* (because of the parentheses) and passes its return value to `addEventListener`, which doesn't do any good. Simply remove the parentheses to pass a reference to the function itself instead of calling it:

```
addbutton.addEventListener( 'click', searchFriendsAsync, false );
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Unfortunately, I don't have enough 'rep' to upvote your answer, but I'll accept it when I can! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, there is a difference between `searchFriendsAsync` and `searchFriendsAsync()`. The first one is just giving a reference to the function that has to be executed. The second one is actually invoking the function.

The onclick attribute expects JavaScript code. Thus you want to execute the function. Thus the parentheses are needed.
However when you specify the button in JavaScript, you would just want to tell the name/reference of the function to be executed I.e. without the parentheses. The `addEventListener` function would make sure that the reference is executed. Thus your code would be like this

`addbutton.addEventListener('click', searchFriendsAsync, false);`